# Explain why $(b_n)\rightarrow0 \mkern10mu\not\mkern-9mu\implies \dfrac{1}{(b_n)}\rightarrow\infty$

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

Explain why $(b_n)\rightarrow0 \mkern10mu\not\mkern-9mu\implies \dfrac{1}{(b_n)}\rightarrow\infty$ by considering the sequence $(b_n)=(-1)^nn^{-2}$

My reasoning is that: $\forall N\in\mathbb{N},\exists C>0,s.t.b_n\le C,\forall n>N.$

For example: $b_1\le1\le\ b_2\le2...$. I'm I missing something?

Comment: You also run into the issue of the sequence $1,0,\frac{1}{2},0,\frac{1}{4},0,\frac{1}{8},0,\frac{1}{16},0,\dots$ successfully satisfying $(b_n)\to 0$ but the sequence $\frac{1}{(b_n)}$ doesn't exist since there would otherwise have been division by zero errors.  You need the additional hypothesis that no $b_i$ is ever *equal* to zero, that or you need to specify that you are working in the extended reals and explicitly allow division by zero, but then what was the result?  $+\infty$ or $-\infty$?  Or are these the same in this context?

Comment: Prove that $b_n$ oscillates and has no unique limit by, say, considering subsequences.

Comment: Your example does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To prove that the implication doesn't hold it suffices to show that

$$b_n =\frac{(-1)^n}{n^2} \to 0$$

but

$$\frac1{b_n}=(-1)^n n^2$$

has not limit since $b_{(2k)} \to \infty$ and $b_{(2k+1)} \to -\infty$.

Comment: Thanks, I've seen this exact proof before, but only just now I understood why it's correct :)

Comment: @u1731182 You are welcome! Bye